# Display Data from Different Database Tables ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

EDIT - I have made progress from the original post and have now made the relevant changes to the question.

In the controller I now have a variable called lstSteps that brings in all the details of the steps that are associated with the relevant Execution.

The problem now is that I am unable to show this list of Steps in the Execution view. I understand that I need to write a foreach loop but cant figure out how to write it.

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Execution(int id = 0)
    {
        Execution execution = db.Executions.Find(id);

var lstSteps = db.Steps.Where(z => z.Execution.Id == id).ToList();  

        if (execution == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds = (execution.End - execution.Start).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");

        return View(execution);

    }
```

### Execution Model

```
namespace DataIntelligence.Models
{
    [Table("Execution")]
    public class Execution
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Int16 PackageId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public Boolean Successful { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Step Model

```
namespace DataIntelligence.Models
{
    [Table("Step")]
    public class Step
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ExecutionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual Execution Execution { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Execution View

```
@model DataIntelligence.Models.Execution
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Execution Details";
}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js">    </script>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Execution Details</h2>
</div>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Execution Id - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)</legend>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PackageId)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Package", new { id=Model.PackageId})">       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PackageId) </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Start)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.End)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.End)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="display-label">
                Execution Time
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="display-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Successful)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Successful)
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <br />

</fieldset>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Step ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var ? in ?) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td style="width: 600px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<button class="btn btn-link" onclick="goBack()" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">Back</button>
```

I believe the parts I am going wrong on is where I have placed the ?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see you have ExecutionId as foreign key from Execution table. Add a navigation property to Step class "public virtual Execution Execution {get; set; }" then you can do linq query to get steps for execution.

Comment: I have added this property to the Step Class, have you any idea how the linq query may look? @Zaki

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: @Zaki please could take a look at my comment on your answer, thanks

Comment: Your `Step` model has a list of `Execution`. Should your `Execution` have a list of Steps? Once you have a list of 'Step' you can use `@foreach(var step in Model.Steps) { // code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add navigation property to `Step` class as you have a foreign key to `Execution` class :

```
public virtual Execution Execution {get; set; }
```

And your `Linq` query would look like this:

```
var lstSteps = db.Steps.Where(z => z.Execution.Id == id).ToList();
```

This will get you all `Steps` where the execution id is equal to the id you are passing. You can Iterate though lstSteps and print it in your view. If you know it will have only one result then use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()`

***EDIT :***

Ok so you want to show a list of Executions with their corresponding Step.

Add another navigation property in `Execution` :

```
public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps {get; set; }
```

change your linq to (this should get `steps` too):

`var Executions = db.Executions.Find(id);`

In your view you can do a foreach :

```
@foreach(var step in Model.Steps) 
{ 
    <label>Step id</label>step .Id; 
    <label>step Name </label>step.Name 
     ....
 }
```

Make sure you your model is : `@model DataIntelligence.Models.Execution`

Comment: Thanks I I have added my linq query (in the controller im guessing) The controller takes in a count of steps the Execution has but now I am struggling to display the list of steps within the view. Sorry for the constant questions but I am a newbie to this. If you could help with this it would be much appreciated

Comment: ok so if you put a break point on the lstSteps do you see a list of steps and executions? if so go to your view and add a foreach loop and go though the Steps and display them

Comment: I've tried a number of different ways of writing the foreach loop and I can't seem to get it working, above I have added the code in my view if you could take a look at that and see where I am going wrong.

Comment: done exactly what you just told but now I get this error? 'DataIntelligence.Models.Execution' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'DataIntelligence.Models.Execution' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What I am wanting is, a page that displays the details of an Execution (each execution has its own details page) on this details page, I also want to show all the steps that take place within the selected Execution - Hopefully this is more helpful

Comment: add using statement to System.Linq, so you have a execution with list of steps ?

Comment: yeah thats it exactly

Comment: see my edit, change the navigation property to collection, then in foreach loop just loop over that nav property and output details

Comment: Thanks for all your help Zaki, I made a slight change to the foreach loop you wrote and managed to get it to work by changing Modal.Execution.Steps to Model.Steps. Again thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just define a new class like this and pass it to your view as your model

```
namespace DataIntelligence.Models
{

    public class ExecutionStep
    {
       public Execution Execution { get;set; }
       public List<Step> Steps { get;set; }  

       public static ExecutionStep Load(int executionStepId)
       {
           // load your execution and step data here and return it
           // within ExecutionStep class object
           ExecutionStep executionStep = new ExecutionStep();
           executionStep.Execution = db.Executions.Find(id); 
           executionStep.Steps = db..... // load steps from db
           return executionStep;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then load ExecutionStep call and can pass it to your view like this

```
public ActionResult Execution(int id = 0)
{
    // now this executionStep class object will serve as a modal 
    // for your view
    ExecutionStep executionStep = ExecutionStep.Load(id);      

    if (execution == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds = (execution.End - execution.Start).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");

    return View(executionStep);
}
```

You can access them in your view like this

```
@Modal.Execution.Start
@foreach(var step in Modal.Steps)
{
}
```

Comment: couldn't get this the work unfortunately. It's throwing out numerous errors such as... The name 'db' does not exist in the current context